# Segmentos de reta saindo do interior de um mapa do brasil utilizando o pacote ggrepel

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico, maps, plot

Estou tentando reproduzir o formato do mapa abaixo, no entanto, venho enfrentando alguns problemas parar inserir essas "retas" no mapa. Após uma pesquisa, encontrei o pacote `ggrepel` que trás consigo uma série de funções capazes de realizar o desejado. Para mais detalhes veja: https://ggrepel.slowkow.com/articles/examples.html.

Eu pretendo inserir um ponto vermelho em cada estado do mapa com a "reta" saindo dele, e posteriormente acrescentar algumas informações numéricas, basicamente seria próximo ao exemplo a seguir:

[image]

Todavia, venho enfrentando o erro que está sendo apresentado no código abaixo.

Os dados estão disponíveis aqui: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TuApNsGtVfNVcGOHmEB-5qVxObRa13V7/view?usp=sharing

`````
library(geobr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

states <- read_state(code_state = "all",year = 2019)
states <- dplyr::left_join(states, dados, by = c("name_state" = "uf"))

ggplot(states) +
  geom_sf(data = states, aes(fill = AreaTotal)) +
  geom_sf_label(aes(label = states$abbrev_state),label.padding = unit(0.8, "mm"),size = 4)+
  geom_point(data = states, color = "red")

Erro: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Além disso: Warning messages:
1: Use of `states$abbrev_state` is discouraged. Use `abbrev_state` instead. 
2: In st_point_on_surface.sfc(sf::st_zm(x)) :
  st_point_on_surface may not give correct results for longitude/latitude data


````
`````

Comment: Neste exemplo, você nem está usando o pacote `ggrepel` . Para as setas deve escolher entre `geom_label_repel()` ou `geom_text_repel()`. Observe que as duas funções querem os pontos/coordenadas onde devam ser inseridas das setas/linhas. Sugiro consultar esse material [aqui](https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2018/10/25/ggplot2-sf-2.html). O erro apresentado entá na função `geom_point()`, valores de x e y faltantes...

Comment: Obrigado Rodrigo Silva!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não uso geobr, usei um shapefile que já possuo, simplificado dos [shapefiles do IBGE](ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2019/Brasil/BR/). Como o geobr acessa o FTP do IBGE, o resultado será o mesmo.

```
library(sf)
library(ggrepel)

states <- st_read("~/Shapefiles/IBGE/ufs.shp")

> head(as.data.frame(states), 3)
#>          NM_ESTADO SIGLA_UF CD_GEOCUF    NM_REGIAO                       geometry
#> 1 Distrito Federal       DF        53 Centro-Oeste POLYGON ((-47.57461 -15.513...
#> 2             Pará       PA        15        Norte POLYGON ((-49.19353 -7.0407...
#> 3             Acre       AC        12        Norte POLYGON ((-67.13424 -9.6762...
```

O erro que está obtendo é porque não está indicando para `geom_point` as coordenadas x e y dos pontos. Objetos sf possuem as coordenadas agrupadas no campo "geometria", precisa indicá-lo na estética. Também precisa indicar para `stat` a função `sf_coordinates`, que converte para coordenadas xy (no caso de um polígono, irá calcular a centróide). O mesmo deve ser feito pra `geom_text_repel`.

```
ggplot(states, aes(geometry = geometry)) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_point(stat = "sf_coordinates", color = "red") +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = SIGLA_UF),
    stat = "sf_coordinates",
    segment.curvature = 1e-20, # para "entortar" a reta
    force = 1e4) +
  theme_void()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usei `force` apenas como exemplo. Para colocar os rótulos nas posições que quer ao redor do mapa, precisará estabelecer os valores de deslocamento para cada ponto com `nudge_x` e `nudge_y` ou fornecer para `data` coordenadas manuais. Veja a ajuda da `geom_text_repel` para detalhes.

## Pontos independentes da geometria do sf

Se tiver coordenadas geográficas dos pontos independente da geometria dos polígonos, pode usar esses dados como base do mapa e incluir o sf por baixo. Eis um exemplo plotando as capitais, usando de base as [coordenadas geográficas dos municípios brasileiros mantida no GitHub por Kelvin S. do Prado](https://github.com/kelvins/Municipios-Brasileiros).

```
centro.mun <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kelvins/Municipios-Brasileiros/main/csv/municipios.csv")

capitais <- merge(as.data.frame(states)[2:3],
                  subset(centro.mun, capital == 1, select = c(2:4,6)),
              by.x = "CD_GEOCUF", by.y = "codigo_uf")

ggplot(capitais, aes(longitude, latitude)) +
  geom_sf(data = states, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = nome), force = 1e3) +
  geom_point(color = "red") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(.2, .4))) + # aumenta espaço lateral
  theme_void()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ficou muito bom. Me questiono se os pontos vermelhos poderiam ser colocados na capital de cada estado, mas acredito que isso adicionaria um nível extra de complexidade ao problema.

Comment: Obrigado Carlos Eduardo.

Comment: @marcus-nunes, sim, os pontos podem ser colocados nas capitais (ou em qualquer outro lugar), mas como a posição nesse caso não é uma função dos polígonos, as coordenadas precisam ser informadas independentemente. Atualizarei a resposta para incluir esse caso.